# Why does the following error pop up when twine uploading files to pypi

Tags: python, module, upload, pypi, twine

When I execute the following lines and put in my information

```
twine upload dist/*
```

The following error pops up

```
HTTPError: 400 Client Error: The description failed to render in the default format of reStructuredText. See https://pypi.org/help/#description-content-type for more information. for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
```

After going to the url, I am not closer to solving the problem. 
My setup.py is the following (with blanked out information)

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="quizmaker",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="my secret name",
    author_email="email",
    description="secret descripting",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="the url",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),

    python_requires='>=3.6',
)
```

If there is any solution to this please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. You forgot to rebuild the distribution or are uploading an old distribution without `long_description_content_type`. Make sure you're starting with an empty `dist` directory, rebuild your distribution and then upload.
2. You're using an old version of some packaging dependency before `long_description_content_type` was supported. You need `setuptools>=38.6.0`, `wheel>=0.31.0` and `twine>=1.11.0`. Upgrade them all with `python -m pip install -U setuptools wheel twine` and then do #1.